# How to abandon zombie jobs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch in a web application. The jobs are run by a custom `TaskExecutor` that manages the submitted `Runnable`s in a queue and executes them one after another. Thus many jobs have the status `STARTING` or `STARTED` for a long time.

Now it happend that the server was shutdown while there were still jobs in the queue. After a restart of the server the jobs are still marked as running, but instead they should be abandoned.

How can this be done?

Comment: what do you think about running a job performs old jobs clean?

Comment: I had a similar idea, but this 'clean up job' should be run automatically on server startup and it should not show up in the `JobRegistry`.

Comment: is the use oif SB mandatatory? because, instead of using SB, use a different tecnique: metadata tables structure is well documented and can be cleaned using standard sql scripts.

Comment: I'm fine with using standard SQL, but where do I have to start the script?

Comment: I don't know. Ask to your sysadmin how to execute custom script on server

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch provides no tools out of the box for something like this.  The reason for that is that this typically requires a human decision of some kind on what conditions this type of behavior is appropriate.

That being said, in your case, if you are not running in a clustered environment, you could create a component that, on the initialization of the application context, examines the job repository and updates the statuses as required (similar to how you can initialize a datasource on startup).

Comment: It's just a single Spring Boot application that has access to the database. I thought about doing the cleanup in the `data.sql` file, but I feel like it's the wrong place for that task.